segmentio/kafka-go consumer delay if GroupID is defined
The problem is when I define in kafka.ReaderConfig  lines GroupID and StartOffset: kafka.LastOffset I have 20-30 seconds delay after the FIRST message is received. So if I wait for these 20-30 seconds and then push the message, consumer recieves it fast.
If I delete these lines consumer recieves messages immediately, but I want to get only new messages.
func New(store *order.Store, cache *cache.OrderCache) *OrderConsumer {
    return &OrderConsumer{
        reader: kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
            Brokers:     []string{config.Envs.KafkaURL},
            Topic:       config.Envs.KafkaTopic,
            GroupID:     "order-group",    // if I comment this, everything is ok
            StartOffset: kafka.LastOffset, // and this 
        }),
        store: store,
        cache: cache,
    }
}

func (oc *OrderConsumer) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    log.Println("Start listening order messages...")
    for {
        log.Println("Waiting for message...")
        msg, err := oc.reader.ReadMessage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error while reading messages: %v", err)
            return err
        }

        log.Printf("Received message: %s", msg.Value)

        var newOrder types.Order
        if err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Value, &newOrder); err != nil {
            log.Printf("order validation error: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        err = oc.store.SaveOrder(&newOrder)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error while saving order to database: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        oc.cache.Set(newOrder.OrderUID, newOrder)
    }
}



Maybe my main function is wrong
func main() {
    pgStorage := db.NewPgStorage()
    pool, err := pgStorage.Init()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer pool.Close()

    orderCache := cache.New(-1, -1)

    orderConsumer := consumer.New(order.NewStore(pool), orderCache)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    go func() {
        if err := orderConsumer.Run(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Consumer error: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    server := api.NewAPIServer(":8000", pool)
    if err := server.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error while starting server %v", err)
    }
}


Your case looks pretty similar to this issue, with the difference that in the end you receive messages after a certain delay.
In both cases trouble seems to arise from StartOffset: kafka.LastOffset
I may suggest you open new issue in segmentio github repo, or add your case to the existing one

Also worth nothing that you might want to play with the configurations of the running Kafka cluster. I'm assuming this is running locally. Defining a group id might be triggering a rebalance that makes that delay happen

I believe it's due to the consumer joining the group and waiting for the cluster to rebalance the partitions between all the consumers in the group. The segmentio/kafka-go library exposes several timeouts that can be adjusted to tune based on your needs. Consider changing the following:

SessionTimeout optionally sets the length of time that may pass without a heartbeat before the coordinator considers the consumer dead and initiates a rebalance. Default: 30s.
RebalanceTimeout optionally sets the length of time the coordinator will wait for members to join as part of a rebalance. For kafka servers under higher load, it may be useful to set this value higher. Default: 30s.

kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers:     []string{config.Envs.KafkaURL},
    Topic:       config.Envs.KafkaTopic,
    GroupID:     "order-group",
    StartOffset: kafka.LastOffset,
    SessionTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    RebalanceTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
})

You may want to expose these timeouts as application configurations because what you need locally versus in production may be different.
